# how to add more history tabs

Tags: firefox, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and i have the latest version of firefox.

When i press ctrl+h i get all the history tabs. (Today/yesterday/last 7 days/this month...)

Well sometimes i go offline and i don't turn on my laptop for 2 days so i have to search my history in the 7 days old history, and that's annoying because there is a lot of history there. It takes a lot of time to search only 1 specific site. So i there a way i can add a new tab, like a 3 or 4 days old history tab ? If yes how ?

Comment: You can get addons to help with history, for example, at a quick glance [Improved History](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/improved-history/) looks like it might be something close to what you want to be able to do (I haven't tried it).

Comment: @AndrewMorton i don't trust add-ons, so if there is any ways to make changes in the default firefox setting that would be great !

Comment: You could [write your own extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension). Or maybe you could find a suitable history one which is open-source and examine the code yourself, but apart from that, I'm not aware of anything more flexible built in. Not that I know all *that* much about Firefox.